# HC-SR04 inaccurate readings

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno

I don't know how I get inaccurate readings from HC-SR04 when I tried to observe its data.

I think I uploaded the program right and perfectly connected the wires to my arduino board (no loose connections/insulations/ etc.) and I think I provided enough power supply, 9v to my arduino uno board.

```
const int Trigger = 9;
const int Echo = 8;

long durationg, inches;

void setup()
{
  pinMode(Trigger, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(Echo, INPUT);
  Serial.begin (9600);
}

void loop()
{
  digitalWrite(Trigger, LOW);
  delay(2);
  digitalWrite(Trigger, HIGH);
  delay(5);
  digitalWrite(Trigger, LOW);
  duration = pulseIn(Echo, HIGH);
  inches = duration / 72 / 2;
  Serial.print(inches);
  Serial.print("in ,");
  Serial.println();
  delay(25);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
const int trigPin = 7;
const int echoPin = 4;
long duration, distance;
void setup() {
  pinMode(trigPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(echoPin, INPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);
}
void loop() {
  digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);
  delayMicroseconds(2);
  digitalWrite(trigPin, HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(10);
  digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);

  duration = pulseIn(echoPin, HIGH);
  distance = duration * 0.034 / 2;

  if (distance < 150) {
    Serial.print(distance);
    Serial.println("  cm");
  }
  if (distance > 150) {
    Serial.println("OUT OF RANGE");
  }
  delay(20);
}
```